# What is the meaning of the warning message when fitting a CNN model ""`sparse_categorical_crossentropy` received `from_logits=True`, but the `output`"

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, softmax

I am trying to fit a CNN model using the below code:

```
model2.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model2=Sequential([
layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255,  input_shape=(180,180,3)),    
layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
layers.MaxPooling2D(),
layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
layers.MaxPooling2D(),
layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
layers.MaxPooling2D(),
layers.Flatten(),
layers.Dense(128,activation='relu'),
layers.Dense(9,activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax)
])
```

I get the error message "

Comment: You should either  remove `from_logits=True` in the second line, or remove `tf.keras.activations.softmax` from your lasy layer.

Comment: Please include the complete error message, the one in the title is incomplete.